# Can't order query results randomly with Peewee

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee, flask-peewee

I am using MySQL with Peewee. Everything has worked nicely, but now I can't order my query in a random order.

Based on the documentation I've tried the following code:

```
import peewee as pw
objz = featured.select().order_by(fn.Rand()).limit(5)
```

After calling the query I got the following error:

> builtins.NameError
>
> NameError: name 'fn' is not defined

So I would like to ask somebody who is more familiar with Peewee, that `fn` is something that I need to import or implement somehow? I already tried `order_by(tablename.Rand()).limit(5)`, but it didn't solve the issue.

I assume I made a beginner mistake somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```py
pw.fn.Rand()

or,

from peewee import fn
```